# How can I split the useful information from this string and output it separately?

Tags: python, discord, steam-web-api

I am using the steam api with python and returning the recently played games of a user. It returns this (albeit as long as how many games the user has launched in the past two weeks, so I will need to limit the amount that is in the string too). [<SteamApp "Blender" (365670)>, <SteamApp "fpsVR" (908520)>, <SteamApp "OVR Toolkit" (1068820)>, <SteamApp "SteamVR" (250820)>]

My code is the following:

```py
    async def recently_played(self, ctx, userurl):
        steam_user = steamapi.user.SteamUser(userurl=userurl)
        await ctx.send(steam_user.recently_played)
```

I tried to remove speech marks, square brackets, arrows and commas but I thought... what if the game has these in their names? I also could not figure out how to get inbetween each parentheses to get rid of the SteamAppID code.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a string back? `print(type(whatever_that_is))` - it looks suspiciously like the default repr from a list of Python objects. Beginner programmers often confuse the string they get from printing something with the actual thing. If in fact that *is* a list, then do `print(type(whatever_that_is[0]))` to see what those objects are. Then you should be able to access attributes of them, like `for game in game_list: print(game.name)`, assuming that they have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there isn't a string or list of strings, it's a list of `SteamApp` objects. Simply access each `SteamApp` object's `name` property to construct a list of names, or to simply print them. There is no need to do all this string manipulation:

```
names = [app.name for app in user.recently_played] # a list of strings
```

Or:

```
for app in user.recently_played:
    print(app.name)
```

Take a look at the source code of [`SteamUser.recently_played`](https://github.com/smiley/steamapi/blob/master/steamapi/user.py#L406) and [`SteamApp.name`](https://github.com/smiley/steamapi/blob/master/steamapi/app.py#L100).

Comment: Good solution. It's possible with string formatting (assuming steam_user.recently_played can be used as a string), but accessing object properties is better.

Comment: @paul M how might I limit the amount that is shown?

Comment: You could slice the original list by replacing `user.recently_played` with `user.recently_played[0:3]` - in this case retaining only the first three items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get an easy-to-read list of the games you could do something like this if the data you are receiving is a string:

```
# get this string from steam_user.recently_played
unformatted = '[<SteamApp "Blender" (365670)>, <SteamApp "fpsVR" (908520)>, <SteamApp "OVR Toolkit" (1068820)>, <SteamApp "SteamVR" (250820)>]'

gameList = unformatted.split('"')[1::2] # returns a list of the games. This is also possible with a regular expression
games = ", ".join(gameList)

print(games)
# returns Blender, fpsVR, OVR Toolkit, SteamVR
```

Comment: to pretty print the list, you could use `", ".join(gameList)`, one-liner without trailing `,`

Comment: @Trevis Thanks, I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: How would I print this all onto one line though? It seems like the solution though

Comment: The problem is @Spencer1O1 that the actual 'unformatted' is a list..